# Create indices from vector of numbers in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have a vector of lengths,

```
lens <- c(3,4,6,8)
```

I want to create indices from this vector, which indicates the total number of indices in each index. The expect output will be 1:3, 4:7, 8:13, 14:21. If in the form of a table, it will be

```
start_idx    end_idx
1            3   #length of index is from length vector
4            7
8            13
14           21
```

Comment: Accepted answer from gcons

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need the `cumsum` here:

```
end_idx <- cumsum(lens)
start_idx <- c(0, head(end_idx,-1)) + 1

data.frame(start_idx, end_idx)

#  start_idx end_idx
#1         1       3
#2         4       7
#3         8      13
#4        14      21
```

Comment: Nice answer but it can be also achieved in a singe line: `data.frame(start_idx = cumsum(lens)-lens+1, end_idx = cumsum(lens))`

Comment: @gcons Nice one liner.

Comment: Thank you, gcons and psidom

Comment: @gcons, you could do `with(list(end = cumsum(lens)), data.frame(start = c(1, head(end,-1)+1), end))` so that you don't have to do `cumsum` twice